# ionic devapp crashes on Android with the "Advanced HTTP" plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, cordova-plugin-advanced-http

I'm developing an ionic 4 app and I had a CORS issue so I followed this article https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/ to install the "advanced http" plugin. I'm using devapp to test my application.

I'm trying http.post to an Azure B2C token URL with headers as `{ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}`

- on iOS DevApp works totally fine
- on Android Studio emulator works fine `ionic cordova run android --emulator`
- on Android Device works fine `ionic cordova run android --device`
- on Android, DevApp crashes with the below error (I was able to get the logs using `adb logcat` and found the error)

> No virtual method getHttpUrlChecked(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl; in class Lokhttp3/internal/Internal; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.Internal' appears in base.apk)

Some posts online suggest its a conflict between different cordova plugins, but I started from a blank template and only used "cordova-plugin-advanced-http", the DevApp instantly crashes.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem in general is a conflict between okHTTP libraries:

https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http/issues/130

Do a case-insensitive "find" ("grep") through all of your project's build files (package.json, build.gradle, config.xml, project.properties, etc. etc.) for "okHTTP".  You should be able to find - and manually correct - the discrepency in the Android build.

Specifically, it looks like you'll have to hack project.properties:

https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/issues/905

Please post back what you find.

PS:

The latest 3.x version of okHTTP is 3.14.4; the latest 4.x version is 4.2.2:

https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog

You *MUST NOT* use a version older than 3.4 for "set/getHttpUrlChecked()" to work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, again I'm not using any other plugins, just the advanced http plugin. Now I did a search and the OKHTTP_VERSION used is 3.10.0 which complies with what you mention (> 3.4.0). Also I should stress that its an issue with devapp on android, if I create an apk and deploy it to my device, it works.

Comment: Dude - it doesn't matter what plugins you explicitly added.  What matters are all the dependencies that might hae been implicitly added behind your back.  Q: Did you "grep -i" for "okhttp" through all potential "build files" related to devapp on android for your project?  What did you find?  ADDITIONAL SUGGESTION: `npm install -g ionic@latest`

Comment: The only place I found OKHttp in the whole project folder was in the advanced http plugin itself. Also I do have the latest angular cli and ionic installed. Sorry frustrating!

Comment: OK: thanks for looking.  If I have time later, I'll try reproducing the problem myself, using the information you've given.  I'll let you know what I find :)